# Jigsaw puzzle with astronaut and alien city

Tags: aliens, object-identification, moon, astronauts, puzzle

I'm trying to find an image from a jigsaw puzzle I had in the early-mid 1970s.  I think I may have seen it on a poster some time later, too.

A space-suited astronaut has climbed to the rim of a crater, probably on the Moon (the terrain is definitely moonscapey), and is looking down on a glowing alien city.  From his posture, he seems astonished (maybe because it should have been impossible not to notice the city while his spacecraft was landing).  His spacecraft, or maybe it was a 'lunar rover'-type vehicle, is visible in the distance at the bottom of the slope.  It might be that he was actually looking through a crevice into a cavern and not down into a crater.

I don't remember whether the picture was in color or not — though it was definitely somewhat monochromatic.  The image had a 1950s–1960s feel to it (i.e. pre-Apollo spacesuit and craft).

Comment: The style of the image you describe makes me think of Chesley Bonestell. He painted a huge amount of space related images and you can see a lot of them on the website dedicated to his art... https://www.bonestell.org In the image gallery there are at least two contenders for an image similar to your description. Also a google search shows at least one of his paintings was made into a jigsaw puzzle. But there are a lot of paintings so impossible for me to guess if this is what you saw. Suggest you take a look for yourself...

Comment: Another artist to take a look at would be Wilf Hardy.

Comment: @skyjack Thanks for the suggestions! Bonestell's art definitely has the right general look, though the puzzle picture wasn't as 'good' or sophisticated.  None of his stuff seems to have an alien city, as far as I can tell.  Hardy's stuff doesn't look like it has the right feel to it, from what I can see online.

Comment: could also try looking at Hubert Rogers, the style on the face of it is a bit gaudy to what you describe but there are definitely alien cities. Take a look at the cover of Mazing Stories July 1947.

Comment: one last suggestion for you, take a look at the painting of Robert McCall Carousel. Its possible from your time scale this is one of the concept images for 2001 A Space Odyssey https://roundupreads.jsc.nasa.gov/history/